# Odoo 8 workflow for project - add new stages for tasks

Tags: workflow, task, odoo-8

I deleted the existing stages in Odoo project and created three stages:

- Todo
- Doing
- Done

How to ensure that the tasks moved to "Done" are assumed as complete (ie. they are no longer highlighted with RED after assigned deadline)?

I tried enabling the Debug view and "Edit Workflow" from the Projects page. The workflow is empty. There is an option to "Import" a csv file. Is there a way to generate this CSV?

**Update1:**

Based on [this bug/explanation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1221124) , I think I have deleted the stages. (extract below)

> Bug Description
>
> This is a usability issue:
>
> After creating a new project, A Project Manager clicks on it project
>   at the Project Kanban view and navigates to the Task Kanban View.
>
> There he deletes one of the Stage, to remove it from it's project
>   stage list. However, this actually deletes the Stage from the Stages
>   table, so it's also removed from all other projects.
>
> My suggestion is to remove the Stages "delete" option at Kanban Views:
>   this should be done only on the Project's definitions Stage list.

Is it possible to **restore the original stages** so that I can use the stage "Completed" for marking tasks as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the stage "Done" as a 'folded' state.

The original stage definitions are contained in the file [`addons/project/project_data.xml`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/project/project_data.xml) and marked as `no_update=='1'` so that they will not be recreated upon updating the project module.

There are three 'folded' stage definitions, which you can refer to with the external IDs `project.project_tt_merge`, `project.project_tt_deployment` (labeled 'Done'), and `project.project_tt_cancel`.

These are suggestions only and can certainly be deleted and replaced with your own definitions.

Comment: Marking as 'folded' is just for visual convenience right? The tasks will still show as incomplete

Comment: Stages marked 'fold==True' are considered final stages. Tasks in such stages do not contribute to the 'task_count' (anymore), nor to the sum of remaining nor planned hours.  By default, these stages are displayed as 'folded' in the kanban view. Opening them in the kanban view is visual only and does not alter their semantics. There is another flag ('closed') which is not really used in the standard modules.

Comment: Great (this is Odoo 8 onwards?)!

Comment: As far as I can tell it's been like this for a while already.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the "Done" activity with the "flow_stop" attribute set to True. That is the way a workflow instance is considered completed.

Info: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/workflows.html